# Azure Databrick: What configuration needs to add in cluster's configuration that helps to parallel execution and how to track applied logs

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I created a message generator Tool that generates files in JSON format and directly writes into azure data lake storage.

**Scenario 1:** To improve in performance,  I have applied java multithreading functionality within code

Use Java ExecutorService for multithreading :

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

I tried to execute on my local machine via IDE  and identified that the process is executing in parallel (No of threads: 5) and there is good improvement in execution time.

While I am using azure Databricks Notebook to execute the same jar file with the below setting, identified that it's executing in serialization and there is no improvement in execution time:

Cluster Mode: Standard
Databrick runtime version: 7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)
Driver and Worker Type: Standard_DS3_v2

**Scenario 2**: Moreover, I have applied logger(`java.util.logging.Logger`) within code so to monitor activities while executing as a jar file.

Created this instance for logger:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataLakeConnection.class.getName());
```

a) I tried to access logs from the "Driver logs" section(track stdout, stderr, log-4j) in the Cluster page of Azure Databrick and unable to found any logs which I have applied as logger in jar file.

b) I tried to access more logs from the "DBFS" section in Azure Databrick using command via the notebook.

**My Question is** :

1. Do we have any configuration that needs to add for Spark cluster's configuration in Azure Databrick which allows parallel execution (in terms of multi-threads)
2. How can we track internal logs in details (the same internal logs applied within jar file)

Thank you in advance :)